# How do refSpecs for push work?

Tags: node.js, nodegit

I'm writing the code based on [this example](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/88e3ec6c7c862919572c5a86701b82587580618a/examples/push.js#L58), but would like to use correct upstream that has been set up for the branch.

```
const branch = await repo.getCurrentBranch();
const branchRefspec = branch.name();
const remoteRefspec = await Git.Branch.upstream(branch);
const remote = await repo.getRemote('origin');
await remote.push(
    [`${branchRefspec}:${remoteRefspec}`],
    {
        callbacks: {
            credentials: verifyUser,
        },
    },
);
```

For some reason, this code does nothing. I couldn't find [any documentation](http://www.nodegit.org/api/remote/#push) on what exactly does this parameter has to be, and what goes after the semicolon. Whatever it is, it doesn't look like [good old git's refspecs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).

If the refspec is left the way it is in example (i.e. from and into the same branch) somehow it works.

Why this code doesn't work? What refspec should I pass there and why?

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the libgit2 folks and your refspecs **must** be of the expanded form `refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master` when pushing. You cannot simply use `master:master`.

Comment: Why not `refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`? It doesn't make any sense to push to the local `master` on a remote.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The `refs/heads/master` on a remote is "your version" of `refs/remotes/origin/master`. Check the [Pushing Refspecs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) section of the link you linked to.